# Controls in Win32 Window (WinAPI via C++)?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

Okay, I have a code that creates a checkbox, however whenever I click on it: it doesn't check. I'm sure I need to put something in the `case WM_COMMAND:`, but I don't know how to check a checkbox when it's clicked. I also need this for a three-state checkbox. And how do you make radio buttons comply with each other? (What I mean is when you click one, it gets checked, and then the radio button you clicked before that is unchecked.)

Comment: Use the `BS_AUTOCHECKBOX` style for checkboxes. The funny thing is that it took me a number of times of doing it manually (via `SendMessage` or `Button_SetCheck`) before I saw that.

Comment: What about radio buttons? BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON ?

Comment: Yes, though I can't recall the last time I used radio buttons. I think it affects all buttons with the same parent.

Comment: And what about GUI transferring? Can I use the dimensions and locations (x & y) of controls from VC++2012Express in CodeBlocks?

Comment: This is well covered by Petzold's "Programming Windows".  Required reading if you want to hack the native api to create UI.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Got the book and reading now. Is there a good tutorial that uses `CreateWindowEx();` to make progressbars? I know zetcode has a good one, but I can't really find their "Resources.h" file online.

Comment: What about Trackbars, Progressbars & Tab controls? Can I create those with `CreateWindowEx();`?

Comment: @Mike: `CreateWindowEx` doesn't create the control _type_; it just creates a new instance. But all types can be created via CreateWindowEx. `RegisterClassEx` creates the actual control types. When you call `InitCommonControlsEx`, it calls `RegisterClassEx` for [the two dozen common controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So I need to use `InitCommonControlsEx()` to load the common controls? For some reason, CodeBlocks (with MinGW) doesn't recognize `InitCommonControlsEx()` even when I include `<commctrl.h>`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 states checkbox using the following code snippet.

```
#define BTN_3STATECHECKBOX           5
#define BTN_AUTO3STATECHECKBOX       6
CreateButton(BS_3STATE, _T("3 State CheckBox"), hWnd, 50, 180, 200, 24, BTN_3STATECHECKBOX);

or 
CreateButton(BS_AUTO3STATE, _T("Auto 3 State CheckBox"), hWnd, 50, 210, 200, 24, ...
```